# Designing a text based logo for a fake "Freelance" site

Tags: logo, icon, illustration

I am trying to create my first text based logo, for a fake website named "Freelance". In theory this website is a common questions and answers website like Stack Overflow. It also has a section for web tutorials. The users of my (fake) website are programmers and designers both asking questions on web design, front end as well as backend development So far I have tried a bird icon with text and some italic fonts.

What should be the main points to focus when designing a logo for above kind of website? Does the below logo suit the requirements?

[image: first logo]

Here is a logo using the pen tool. Does this fits the requirements?

[image: second logo]

Comment: Is it a complete logo? You mentioned 'bird icon'.

Comment: This one is another logo, I have deleted that bird icon

Comment: Most well crafted text-based logotypes are more than merely choosing a font.

Comment: Hi @Scott, so you mean the second one would be more suitable for the requirement ?

Sorry for many questions, I have started my logo design from today only

Comment: There is no harm to considering a logo before a product launch, but the 'school' exercise to create a log is a good one. I didn't see the original with the bird. But the pen tool I do see. What is the significance of a bird?

Comment: I simply mean that *often* although a specific typeface may be the *basis* for a text logo, quite often the glyphs are intentionally manipulated in some way to create a more *unique* mark. After all, few companies want a logotype that your grandma can recreate by clicking a font menu twice.

Comment: The 2nd example (with stylized "r") looks like "Freela**m**ce" to me.

Comment: @TripeHound That's not how cursive writing in English works. It's clearly an "n".

Comment: That `an` combination is pretty poorly drawn and *does* look like an `m` to me as well. It's not "how cursive in English works" nor is it "clearly an n". The tail of the `a` should never create an entirely new, and *separate*, vertical. That appearance is either `ain` or `am`.

Comment: Agree @Scott its not looking good, I am working on to polish the shape, I think width needs to be adjusted to make it look like above font. 

This time I will first sketch it precisely on the paper before drawing it directly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you talk about a logo you have to consider-

what the client wants,
who the audience is,
what is the purpose of that brand
and
what kind of logo the opponents have ( to avoid copyright issues).

And the text-based logo is not only about fonts!!!

It has to be geometrically presentable and aesthetic too.

You have to consider subtle symbolic components, color psychology as well.

Two famous examples are  FedEx and Amazon. Kindly check how beautifully the designer presented the theme in the name.

Kindly research, spend some time, design 3/ 4 rough concepts, and then pick the best one, polish that more.

Good luck.

Answer (score 6):

You should focus on the product first, then think about the logo. If you think about it, people don't visit a website to see the logo, they visit the website, because it is useful.
About the logo ... it's alright but I think you should create a custom connection between the F and r letters, because now there is a gap there.

Comment: Hi @Komental, Actually I have given the scenario of fake website, I am learning logo design. Thanks for your advice though I will add connection b/w letters.

Comment: @NiteeshBhargava This is a very lazy way to create a logo ... just writing a word with some font. What did you learn really? What are you trying to learn?

Comment: @NiteeshBhargava I think this answer applies, even for a fake website.  Is the Freelance website intended for freelance journalists? Or designers? Or programmers?  The design will need to be different in each case.  Build the hypothetical scenario in your own mind, then think through what that means for your logo.

Comment: Hi @Komental , 

Based on your  comments , I have added one more logo using pen tool, can you suggest if this is making the requirement ?

Comment: @NiteeshBhargava I once did same, like I worked on my artwork and updated it on my question, I guess it's not allowed  Why not share it on a site like imgur and comment the link? Also there's a specific room for feedback which might wanna have a look: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36555/the-looking-glass

Comment: Correction to my comment: It may be allowed, but perhaps not encouraged.